# How to access values from another dart file?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter .Here I stored a value to a variable `doc_id` ,I want to use this value in another file called comments.dart . So I did something like below but it gives null value in comment.dart .

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('blogs')
    .add({
    'title': titleController.text,                         
}).then((value) {
  doc_id = value.id;

  comment(postid: docid);

  successAlert(context);
}).catchError((error) => 
 errorAlert(context));
```

Comment.dart

```
class comment extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? postid;
  const comment({Key? key, this.postid}) : super(key: key);
  _commentState createState() => _commentState();
}

class _commentState extends State<comment> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return        
        Text(widget.postid);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Are you calling firestore method into a initstate?

Comment: Do you want get doc_id in comment.dart file?

Comment: Yes I want to get the doc_id in comment.dart .And I didn't called the firestore method in initstate .Firestore method is given inside an onpressed method .

Comment: @Devika When on press method is called you have to pass id into comment screen... is its working then please give me snippet so i posted

Comment: Onpressed method doesnt navigate to comment.dart page

Comment: Can you please tell me where is your firebase methid?

Comment: let me update my question .

Comment: @Devika Or where is locate your onpress method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250919/discussion-between-rahulvflutterandroid-and-devika).

Comment: Please follow the naming guidelines for Dart.  In particular your classname should have an initial cap.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a global variable and assign from there

```
String postid = "";

class comment extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? postid;
  const comment({Key? key, this.postid}) : super(key: key);
  _commentState createState() => _commentState();
}

class _commentState extends State<comment> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return        
        Text(postid);
  } 
}

void setPostID(String s) {  // get value
   postid = s;
}
```

Finally assign the value

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('blogs')
    .add({
    'title': titleController.text,                         
}).then((value) {
  doc_id = value.id;
  
  setPostID(value.id);   // set value

  comment(postid: docid);

  successAlert(context);
}).catchError((error) => 
 errorAlert(context));
```

Comment: I want to store this value.id permanently into a variable so that I can acess my subcollection.Using the above the setPostID will only get triggered whenever we add something to collection "blogs"

Comment: I added another ans. chk on that

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('blogs')
    .add({
    'title': titleController.text,                         
}).then((value) {
  doc_id = value.id;
  
  await prefs.setString('doc_id', postid);   // set value

  comment(postid: docid);

  successAlert(context);
}).catchError((error) => 
 errorAlert(context));
```

Finally use it in your class

```
class comment extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? postid;
  const comment({Key? key, this.postid}) : super(key: key);
  _commentState createState() => _commentState();
}

class _commentState extends State<comment> {

  @override
  void initState() {    
    super.initState();
    widget.postid = prefs.getString('doc_id');  // get the value
    setState(() {});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return        
        Text(postid);
  } 
}
```